# How do I copy all files from one directory into matched files of another?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, copy-paste, bash-scripting

For exmaple I have 2 directories with the following structures

Directory 1

```
./img/1.jpg
./img/2.jpg
./img/3.jpg
./img/4.jpg
```

Directory 2

```
./thumb/1.jpg
./thumb/2.jpg
./thumb/3.jpg
```

How do I copy only the matched files from ./thumb (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg) from ./img into ./thumb  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple bash loop:

```
for f in thumb/*.jpg;do cp img/$(basename $f) thumb;done
```

(`basename` returns the name of the file with all the directory components removed).

Comment: That's a great bash solution. Is there a way to do it via a terminal command?

Comment: @JesusAltorez you can execute that in a terminal